# Adding numbers to my APA references

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style, apacite

I need to use APA for my text, which I have now, but I also need my bibliography to be numbered [1] blabh blah, sorted as it is now (alphabetically).

```
     \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
     \usepackage{apacite}
     \bibliographystyle{apacite}


     \bibliography{referanser}
```

Does anyone know how to do this? (with Bibtex)
(my bibliography is referanser.bib)

Comment: This is contradictory, apa is an author year style.

Comment: If `biblatex` is an option, it's possible. Not so simple with `apacite` I think. See [APA bibliography style with numbers](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/373336).

Comment: @Johannes_B It's not contradictory to number the bibliography items formatted as APA; it's only contradictory for the in text citations. You might want to number items in, e.g. a CV.

Comment: Yes, I use author-year for the in-text citations. I do not want numbers in the text, just in the bibliography.

Comment: If authoryear-style citation call-outs are generated in the body of  the document, affixing numbers to the formatted bibliographic items does nothing but provide visual clutter.

Comment: @AlanMunn Is it not possible with bibtex? If I change to biblatex, do I not have to change different things then? It is a very large document.

Comment: @mico sure, but that is the required format.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do this with plain `apacite` (it won't work if you use the `[natbibapa]` option; that would require a different method.)

You can adjust the two lengths `\bibleftmargin` and `\bibindent` to your liking. For example, if you don't need the hanging indent, you can set `\bibleftmargin` to `2.5em` and `\bibindent` to `0em`.

You can change the formatting of the number itself by changing the definition of `\thebibcount`:

```
\renewcommand{\thebibcount}{\arabic{bibcount}.}  % puts dot after it
\renewcommand{\thebibcount}{[\arabic{bibcount}]} % put number in [ ]
```

Here's a complete example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Ansoff2007,
address = {London},
author = {Ansoff, H. Igor},
edition = {Classic Ed},
isbn = {978-0-230-52548-1},
pages = {272},
publisher = {Palgrave Macmillan UK},
title = {{Strategic Management}},
year = {2007}
}

@article{Webster2002,
    Author = {Webster, Jane and Watson, Richard T},
    Journal = {Source: MIS Quarterly},
    Keywords = {WA},
    Number = {2},
    Title = {{Analyzing the Past to Prepare for the Future: Writing a Literature Review}},
    Url = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/4132319},
    Volume = {26},
    Year = {2002},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{bibcount}
\renewcommand{\thebibcount}{\arabic{bibcount}.} % format number
\patchcmd{\@lbibitem}{\item[}{\item[\stepcounter{bibcount}{\hss\llap{\thebibcount}\quad}}{}{}
\setlength{\bibleftmargin}{5em}
\setlength{\bibindent}{-2em}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\section{Section}
Cite:               \cite{Ansoff2007} \\
Cite page:          \cite[p. 5]{Webster2002} \\
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: That works indeed! Thank you so much, do you think it is possible to get it like 

[1] Ansoff,
[2] Webster etc. 

as well? Including the brackets I mean.

Comment: @Olivia I've updated the code to separate the formatting of the number from the patching command.